# c# Windows Form slow rendering objects

Tags: c#, winforms

I have spent some time designing my first project using C#, it is a Windows form project with 8 buttons on the side. pressing one of the buttons will open another form within the parent form as a window. On clicking the button the new form loads up about 27 objects mostly Labels, Textboxes, Comboboxes and a few DateTimePickers. For some reason it you can see it drawing the boxes and it looks slow. I have an SQL db included with my project which is tiny and contains only 2 rows of data. It is very dishearting to spend all that time working on it only to see it run like a ZX Spectrum. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 and is fully updated. I have no errors, no warnings thank god but the performance is horrible. One of the comboBoxes when selected will make visible 3 more textBoxes and even making those visible is really slow. Is there something I am doing wrong or is there a way to have it working faster please?
This is the code of my childForm which opens from the main parentForm, sorry is is a bit long but it is all of it.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace AvianManager.Forms
{
    public partial class formMyBirds : Form
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Dion\Documents\AvianManager.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");

        public formMyBirds()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void formMyBirds_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var form = Application.OpenForms["formMyBirdsHelper"]; // Lookup form and check if already open
            if (form == null)
            {
                formMyBirdsHelper MyBirdsHelper = new formMyBirdsHelper(); // Instantiate a FormMyBirdsHelp object.
                MyBirdsHelper.Show(); // Show FormMyBirdsHelp and
            }
        }

        private void comboBoxLegBandType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string selected = this.comboBoxLegBandType.GetItemText(this.comboBoxLegBandType.SelectedItem);
            if (selected != "None" || selected == null)
            {
                textBoxLegBandID.Visible = true;
                labelLegBandId.Visible = true;
                textBoxLegBandSize.Visible = true;
                labelLegBandSize.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                textBoxLegBandID.Visible = false;
                labelLegBandId.Visible = false;
                textBoxLegBandSize.Visible = false;
                labelLegBandSize.Visible = false;
            }
        }

        private void comboBoxPrevOwner_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string selected = this.comboBoxPrevOwner.GetItemText(this.comboBoxPrevOwner.SelectedItem);
            if (selected != "No")
            {
                textBoxLastOwnerName.Visible = true;
                labelLastOwnerName.Visible = true;
                textBoxLastOwnerFone.Visible = true;
                labelLastOwnerFone.Visible = true;
                textBoxLastOwnerAddr.Visible = true;
                labelLastOwnerAddr.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                textBoxLastOwnerName.Visible = false;
                labelLastOwnerName.Visible = false;
                textBoxLastOwnerFone.Visible = false;
                labelLastOwnerFone.Visible = false;
                textBoxLastOwnerAddr.Visible = false;
                labelLastOwnerAddr.Visible = false;
            }
        }

        private void comboBoxVitalStatus_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string selected = this.comboBoxVitalStatus.GetItemText(this.comboBoxVitalStatus.SelectedItem);
            if (selected != "Alive")
            {
                dateTimeDateOfDeath.Visible = true;
                labelDateOfDeath.Visible = true;
                textBoxCauseOfDeath.Visible = true;
                labelCauseOfDeath.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                dateTimeDateOfDeath.Visible = false;
                labelDateOfDeath.Visible = false;
                textBoxCauseOfDeath.Visible = false;
                labelCauseOfDeath.Visible = false;
            }
        }

        private void comboBoxRetained_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string selected = this.comboBoxRetained.GetItemText(this.comboBoxRetained.SelectedItem);
            if (selected != "Yes")
            {
                dateTimeRelinquishedDate.Visible = true;
                labelRelinquishedDate.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                dateTimeRelinquishedDate.Visible = false;
                labelRelinquishedDate.Visible = false;
            }
        }

        private void textBoxUid_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select top 1 * from dbMyBirds where db_Uid = '" + textBoxUid.Text + "'", connection);

            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("db_Uid", textBoxUid.Text);
            SqlDataReader reader1;
            connection.Open();
            reader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader1.Read())
            {
                labelResult.Text = "Found";
                textBoxName.Text = reader1["db_Name"].ToString();
                textBoxSpecies.Text = reader1["db_Species"].ToString();
                comboBoxLegBandType.Text = reader1["db_LegBandType"].ToString();
                textBoxLegBandID.Text = reader1["db_LegBandId"].ToString();
                textBoxLegBandSize.Text = reader1["db_LegBandSize"].ToString();
                comboBoxPrevOwner.Text = reader1["db_PrevOwner"].ToString();
                textBoxLastOwnerName.Text = reader1["db_PrevOwnerName"].ToString();
                textBoxLastOwnerFone.Text = reader1["db_PrevOwnerFone"].ToString();
                textBoxLastOwnerAddr.Text = reader1["db_PrevOwnerAddr"].ToString();
                comboBoxIsHybrid.Text = reader1["db_Hybrid"].ToString();
                comboBoxRearedBy.Text = reader1["db_RearedBy"].ToString();
                textBoxDisformaties.Text = reader1["db_Disformaties"].ToString();
                comboBoxVitalStatus.Text = reader1["db_VitalStatus"].ToString();
                dateTimeDateOfDeath.Text = reader1["db_DateDied"].ToString();
                textBoxCauseOfDeath.Text = reader1["db_CauseOfDeath"].ToString();
                comboBoxRetained.Text = reader1["db_Retained"].ToString();
                dateTimeRelinquishedDate.Text = reader1["db_RelinquishedDate"].ToString();
                dateTimeHatchDate.Text = reader1["db_HatchDate"].ToString();
                dateTimeFledgeDate.Text = reader1["db_FledgeDate"].ToString();
                comboBoxMaleParentHybrid.Text = reader1["db_MPisHybrid"].ToString();
                textBoxMaleParentId.Text = reader1["db_MPUid"].ToString();
                textBoxMaleParentSpecies.Text = reader1["db_MPSpecies"].ToString();
                comboBoxHenParentHybrid.Text = reader1["db_FPisHybrid"].ToString();
                textBoxHenParentId.Text = reader1["db_FPUid"].ToString();
                textBoxHenParentSpecies.Text = reader1["db_FPSpecies"].ToString();
                textBoxNotes.Text = reader1["db_Notes"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                resetInputs();
                if (textBoxUid.Text == "")
                {
                    labelResult.Text = "Live Search";
                }
                else
                {
                    labelResult.Text = "Nothing Found";
                }
            }
            connection.Close();
        }

        //Reset input fields if no results
        private void resetInputs()
        {
            string dt2;
            DateTime date2 = DateTime.Now;
            dt2 = date2.ToShortDateString(); // display format:  15/07/2021
            textBoxName.Text = "";
            textBoxSpecies.Text = "";
            comboBoxLegBandType.Text = "Select";
            textBoxLegBandID.Text = "";
            textBoxLegBandSize.Text = "";
            comboBoxPrevOwner.Text = "Select";
            textBoxLastOwnerName.Text = "";
            textBoxLastOwnerFone.Text = "";
            textBoxLastOwnerAddr.Text = "";
            comboBoxIsHybrid.Text = "Select";
            comboBoxRearedBy.Text = "Select";
            textBoxDisformaties.Text = "";
            comboBoxVitalStatus.Text = "Select";
            dateTimeDateOfDeath.Text = dt2;
            textBoxCauseOfDeath.Text = "";
            comboBoxRetained.Text = "Select";
            dateTimeRelinquishedDate.Text = dt2;
            dateTimeHatchDate.Text = dt2;
            dateTimeFledgeDate.Text = dt2;
            comboBoxMaleParentHybrid.Text = "Select";
            textBoxMaleParentId.Text = "";
            textBoxMaleParentSpecies.Text = "";
            comboBoxHenParentHybrid.Text = "Select";
            textBoxHenParentId.Text = "";
            textBoxHenParentSpecies.Text = "";
            textBoxNotes.Text = "";
        }

        private void buttonInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code has nothing special, only this textBoxUid_TextChanged event may slow down. I feel that you have set the text box change event incorrectly

Comment: Yes, that works as a live search. I tried removing that code before but it made no difference at all

Comment: Do you *need* to intercept paint events? I'm wondering whether the `panel1_Paint` method might be part of this. If you could provide a [mcve], that would help...

Comment: You have something there that you're not mentioning, as gigantic background image, possibly taken from the Project's Resources (or never disposed of). Other stuff that you may be drawing somewhere. Or, you are creating multiple instances of this Form -- You should not be using a Form as an UserControl.

Comment: I was not sure how to change that. I tried removing the Event but I get build errors. I could not see anything in the property window on the paint method neither.

Comment: To remove an event handler, just select a Control, go to PropertyGrid, switch to the Events view and delete the handler. If, for some reason, the handler method remains in the code window, just delete that code.

Comment: I removed the event and there was a MyBirds_Load Event too which I also removed, Built it again and executed the code. It does work a little bit faster but still has some way to go. There are no large photos or images anywhere in the application. There is a Panel which goes out of the bottom of the screen because it has other objects on it and scroll has been enabled to view that part.

Comment: This is an unusual problem. I'm guessing you have a weird problem wiring things up, e.g. a control that is repainting too often or some sort of cascading event, but it's impossible to tell without going through your actual code. I suggest recreating the form from scratch, a few controls at a time, until the problem starts again, and reviewing what it was you did last that caused the issue to start.

Comment: You probably only ran your code in Debug mode. Try compiling it in Release.

Comment: Some controls, such as DataGridView, are slow to render due to single buffering enabled by default. When double buffering is enabled, rendering occurs instantly.

Comment: There are no DataGridView being used. I think John Wu had a great idea which is starting again and check as I go but this will be a lot of work I guess. Yes I have only run it in Debug mode but will try a release version. I wish I knew how to share a project, for someone experienced the code will be small and probably simple but I don't want to waste anyones time.

Comment: You can zip the Solution's folder and post it somewhere (e.g., Google Drive) and share the link. - Drawing issue can also be related to the Parent Container Form. Or a Time that performs some actions too frequently. Or some third-part Controls. Anyway, as mentioned, what's shown here doesn't cause the problem (except that this is not the way to handle a Connection object and you should not have that code in the `TextChanged` handler).

Comment: Hi Jimi, I have zipped the whole folder, I also dragged in the db file and this is the link to download from my server. http://www.finchkeeper.com:14147/AvianManager.zip

Comment: I would suggest learning how to use a performance profiler. This often reveals interesting and unexpected things. There is a decent one built into visual studio, but there are also trial versions of some third party ones. A poor mans alternative is to use the break all button repeatedly during slow parts and checking what the computer is doing. Chances are 95% of the time is spent doing unnecessary work, or being blocked for one reason or another.

Comment: Well, I gave the Project a look. There's nothing here that's slows rendering of any Form down. There's just one Form that has something inside, the one you mentioned here. A few Controls that load up in a few milliseconds. You said you have the same problem disabling the DB Connection -- A few FontAwsome controls that are only used in the starting Form. -- What I could not test (or see what's for) is a WebApp DataBase that is not functional (removed). From what I can see, there's nothing here that can slow down the rendering of any Form. BTW, your Project is 32-bit, fix that.

Comment: I don't remember saying I had problems disabling the DB connection, that seems to work fine. The DB I was trying to use was one that was deployable with the finished software. You pointed out some good things which I overlooked. It is now x64 instead of x32. I will explore a more appropiate type of DB system for this project as everything will depend on it. thanks

Comment: We have same problem with our legacy windows forms application. That is main reason why this project is stuck with visual studio 2017, because in VS2017 there is no performance problems. Tried to search for a solution when VS2019 came out, and didn`t suceed. Now I tried VS2022 - same problem, nothing changed. 
Problem is when you run application from VS and open windows form it opens like 5x slower than in VS2017, you can see each control slowly drawing on screen until form is loaded.